# How do I customize NSOutlineView to have border color?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nsoutlineview

I have looked over the google but have not found many examples on this. Most only relate to the NSTableView.

How do I subclass my NSOutlineView to look exactly like XCode's plist editor? I've do not know how to get the border colors shown below. I currently have it working exactly the same, except for the coloring. Any help would be appreciated. 
[image]

**UPDATE**
The part I am confused about is what the draw code should look like. Google didnt help me much on this.

Comment: The bit you say you're stuck on is essentially just drawing on an ``NSView`` - the internet has plenty of basic tutorials on this; here's a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919102/whats-the-preferred-recommended-way-to-draw-a-line-in-nsview-drawrect-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Create an `NSTableViewRow` subclass**

The borders are drawn on the `NSTableRowView` instances that make up the table's rows. To get them, you could subclass `NSTableRowView` and give it a `borders` property that stores a mask specifying which borders you want drawn on the row. You'd accompany this with a custom implementation of `drawRect`, which calls *super* first, and then strokes on the specified borders.

**Step 2: Implement the delegate methods that signal when you'll need to update the borders**

In the simplest case, I can think of three:

```
- (void)outlineViewItemWillExpand:(NSNotification *)notification
- (void)outlineViewItemDidCollapse:(NSNotification *)notification
- (NSIndexSet *)         outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView 
selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:(NSIndexSet *)proposedSelectionIndexes
```

**This is where you'll find the hard work**. I'd start by having a go at the last one first. There will be lots of different ways of doing it, but you could get the node that's about to be selected from the `proposedSelectionIndexes` argument in conjunction with the `NSOutlineView` api. Once you've got this node you can work out which rows will need a border by getting the nodes represented in the rows below this soon-to-be-selected row. If a given node is a descendant of the new selection, then it'll need a border of some sort (hint: the `indexPath` property of `NSTreeNode` comes in handy here).

**Step 3: Make sure the outline view is using your custom row views**

Implement the following delegate method so that it returns your custom row views:

```
 - (NSTableRowView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView rowViewForItem:(id)item
```

Note that the second `item` argument is an `NSTreeNode` object. By keeping a record (a map of some sort) of which nodes are associated with which borders, you can then set the `border` mask property of your `NSTableRowView` subclass.

Comment: can you help me one last time? I'd like for you to explain a bit more on the borders property.